# vim: Making tabbed behaviour default

Tags: vim, app-startup

TIL that vim 7 has the ability to work with tabs which is cool.
Is there a way to tell vim through .vimrc that whenever I open multiple files, open them in tabs [instead of having to use -p always]

Comment: create an alias maybe?

Comment: I understand you are asking me to alias vim to vim -p..
But can that be done in the vimrc file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, I think slightly better then the tabedit autocommand from Ingo is

```
:au VimEnter * set tabpagemax=9999|sil tab ball|set tabpagemax&vim
```

which at least avoids the empty tabpage being created.

Comment: Probably `all` is better than `ball` here so as to create a new tab for each page in the argument list rather than the buffer list? But I don't know under what cases the behaviour would differ between using `all` or `ball`.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
:autocmd VimEnter * argdo tabedit
```

This edits each file in the *argument list* (i.e. all files passed on the command line) in a new tab page. It's probably still a bit raw and doesn't handle corner cases too well, but see this as a starting point.

Comment: For some reason when I try this & execute `vim 1 2 3`, the files are open in tabs all right but there is a fourth tab with an empty file. Any guesses why?

Comment: Same here. Also it asks me to press ENTER once for every file before opening all of them:

    `"file1" 6500L, 2173458C
    "file_a_b_c" 2553 lines, 816646 characters
    Press ENTER or type command to continue
    "file_b_c_d" 10 lines, 100 characters
    Press ENTER or type command to continue`

and so on..

Comment: @Paddu That's because of `:tabedit`; it should probably just `:edit` the first one. I hinted at this "raw" behavior; feel free to tweak it as you please.

Comment: @radiantRazor Use `:silent` before either `argdo` or `tabedit` (should work in both locations), this way you will not get these messages. Try using `:execute "argdo tabedit" | tabclose 1` in place of `argdo tabedit` to remove both messages and first tab page.

Comment: @ZyX, I added in my .vimrc `autocmd VimEnter * execute "argdo tabedit" | tabclose 1` and executed `vim 1 2 3` and found that three tabs where open, fir the files `2`, `3` and an empty file.